# How do I get the current timestamp in an aggregate pipeline in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to do some arithmetic with dates with my data using MongoDB's aggregate query feature.

My main issue is getting the current date and subtracting it from a date value set on the collection.

Example record:

```
[
 {
   _id: '1',
   upcomingDate: ISODate('2019-12-31T23:59:00.000Z')
 }
]
```

My pipeline:

```
[
{ "$match": { ... },
{ "$project: { 
    timeToGo: { "$subtract": ["$upcomingDate", new Date()] }
  } 
}
]
```

Unfortunately, `new Date()` results in an error:

```
MongoError: cant $subtract a String from a Date
```

My initial idea was that `$upcomingDate` is being read as a `string`, alas, setting the values to `[new Date(), new Date()]` resulted in this error:

```
MongoError: cant $subtract a String from a String
```

I am on using Node.js to write the query and our db is WiredTiger v3.2, and am currently unable to upgrade due to a limitation with our provider MLabs.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any chance are you converting `upcomingDate` to a string in your nodejs code?

Comment: Nope, otherwise the first error log would have stated `String from a String`